# Python Regex Split Keeps Split Pattern Characters

Tags: python, regex

Easiest way to explain this is an example:
I have this string: 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp'
Which I know how to split two different ways:

```
re.split('/', 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp') -> ['Docs', 'src', 'Scripts', 'temp']

re.split('(/)', 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp') -> ['Docs', '/', 'src', '/', 'Scripts', '/', 'temp']
```

Is there a way to split by the forward slash, but keep the slash part of the words?
For example, I want the above string to look like this:

```
['Docs/', '/src/', '/Scripts/', '/temp']
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's `re.split('(/)',...)`, not `re.split(('/'),...)`.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
>>> 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp'.replace('/', '/\x00/').split('\x00')
['Docs/', '/src/', '/Scripts/', '/temp']
```

The idea here is to first replace all `/` characters by two `/` characters separated by a special character that would not be a part of the original string.  I used a null byte (`'\x00'`), but you could change this to something else, then finally split on that special character.

Regex isn't actually great here because you cannot split on zero-length matches, and `re.findall()` does not find overlapping matches, so you would potentially need to do several passes over the string.

Also, `re.split('/', s)` will do the same thing as `s.split('/')`, but the second is more efficient.

Comment: Doing the split and join is like `'Docs/src/Scripts/temp'.replace('/', '/\x00/')`

Comment: @gnibbler - Silly me, thanks that is much cleaner!  Edited my answer to use that instead.

Comment: Wow! Very nice, much better than mine.

Comment: `re.findall() does not find overlapping matches` But it does within a lookaround. I came up with this findall: `(?=((?:^|/)[^/]+/?))`, capturing the strings to Group 1. Then saw that Tim had posted the same except for the `+`  @OP on the [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jM3vK9/1) the captures are in the **right pane**. Sorry for stalking you today Andrew, reading answers from people on the All-Time regex users, started with you. Ciao!

Comment: @zx81 Definitely didn't mind the stalking, thanks for the thoughtful comments and upvotes :)

Comment: Ha, you have some interesting ones. :) Only had time to read from your most upvoted to those that got 6 ups, but if you're like me some of your best regex answers only have 2 or 3 ups.

Answer (score 5):

A solution without `split()` but with lookaheads:

```
>>> s = 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp'
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?=((?:^|/)[^/]*/?))")
>>> r.findall(s)
['Docs/', '/src/', '/Scripts/', '/temp']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?=        # Assert that it's possible to match...
 (         # and capture...
  (?:^|/)  #  the start of the string or a slash
  [^/]*    #  any number of non-slash characters
  /?       #  and (optionally) an ending slash.
 )         # End of capturing group
)          # End of lookahead
```

Since a lookahead assertion is tried at every position in the string and doesn't consume any characters, it doesn't have a problem with overlapping matches.

Comment: Ha, I worked this question just for fun and came out with the same regex as you, character for character! (Except I had a `+` where you had a `*`) :) +1

Answer (score 3):

1) You do not need regular expressions to split on a single fixed character:

```
>>> 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp'.split('/')
```

['Docs', 'src', 'Scripts', 'temp']

2) Consider using this method:

```
import os.path

def components(path):
    start = 0
    for end, c in enumerate(path):
        if c == os.path.sep:
            yield path[start:end+1]
            start = end
    yield path[start:]
```

It doesn't rely on clever tricks like split-join-splitting, which makes it much more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on having slashes on both sides, it's actually quite simple:

```
>>> re.findall(r"([^/]*/)", 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp')
['Docs/', 'src/', 'Scripts/']
```

Neither `re` nor split are really cut out for overlapping strings, so if that's what you really want, I'd just add a slash to the start of every result except the first.

Answer (score 2):

Try about this:

```
re.split(r'(/)', 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp')
```

From python's documentation

> **re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)**
>
> Split string by the
> occurrences of pattern. ***If capturing parentheses are used in pattern,
> then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part
> of the resulting list.*** If maxsplit is nonzero, at most maxsplit splits
> occur, and the remainder of the string is returned as the final
> element of the list. (Incompatibility note: in the original Python 1.5
> release, maxsplit was ignored. This has been fixed in later releases.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to do this.  This is the best I could come up with...

```
import re

lSplit = re.split('/', 'Docs/src/Scripts/temp')
print [lSplit[0]+'/'] + ['/'+x+'/' for x in lSplit][1:-1] + ['/'+lSplit[len(lSplit)-1]]
```

Kind of a mess, but it does do what you wanted.

Comment: Why do you need regular expressions when you just split on a single character anyway?

Comment: You don't.  You could use a str.split() if you wanted.  F.J's answer is better than mine anyway.